# There isn't ANY "CFBundleIcons" entry in the Info.plist of the app. So how to solve this RIDICULOUS error??? : ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path"

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

After about 5 days of working 12 hour days to get iCloud functioning perfectly in an app, when validating the app for upload to the app store this error happened:

ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'"

There isn't ANY such entry in the Info.plist in the app and actually there isn't ANY icons related entry in that Info.plist file.

How to solve that RIDICULOUS xcode error??? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: did u find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Same issue, did you guys find a solution for this?